# Visual Studio 2017 Auto Update Nuget Packages to Central Folder

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

I have WebApplication that I started on a different machine. Since the repository does not store the Nuget packages I have to restore all the packages. I also want to install the packages to a separate hard drive which can be shared by other projects.

The project was built in Visual Studio 2015. The new machine uses Visual Studio 2017. I would like to either have visual studio automatically install the missing packages or build the project and have the packages download automatically.

Nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
    <config>
        <add key="repositorypath" value="C:\Nuget\packages\" />
    </config>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Package source" value="C:\Nuget\packages" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

Is there a conflict because of the different software versions or am I doing something wrong?